# Copying code from Mathematica to SE

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to get help on a series of differential equation but I'm running into trouble when attempting to copy the code into S.E. The results look garbled and I'm not sure it's understandable by others (see example). Is there a way to improve the formating ?

```
e6 = de/(r*tp[w]*radius^2)*(\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x, x\)]\(psco2[x]\)\) + 2/x*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x\)]\(psco2[x]\)\)) + 
rho*(-r1[x, w] - r2[x, w]) == 0;
```

Comment: I guess I'm old school, but I avoid using fancy formatted input in the first place.

Comment: @george2079 when I came to undergraduate P-Chem lab, and they introduced me to *Mathematica*, one of the first things I played with was the [palettes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dNYBg.png) like these, so hard to resist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you upload an Image in addition? Sure, not the best option...

[image]

Comment: However, normally one would copy your code into Mma I guess, so the format will be secured than...

Comment: I did not realized Mma would process it back... Good to know.

Answer (score 5):

Before you copy the code, right-click on the cell bracket (on the right) corresponding to this cell.  Then select `Convert To -> Raw InputForm`, which changes your code to

```
e6 = (de/(r*tp[w]*radius^2))*(D[psco2[x], x, x] + (2/x)*
        D[psco2[x], x]) + 
         rho*(-r1[x, w] - r2[x, w]) == 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

After copying and executing your code in Mathematica, I executed

```
% // InputForm
```

The result is

```
rho*(-r1[x, w] - r2[x, w]) + (de*((2*Derivative[1][psco2][x])/x + 
    Derivative[2][psco2][x]))/(r*radius^2*tp[w]) == 0
```

as it should be.